# Greater Than and Less Than Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to go through random numbers between 0 and 1 and group them into an array.  Each array holds the value of numbers from 0 to 0.1, 0.1 to 0.2, etc. How do I write the `If` statement to get my code to include the 0.1? As of now, it is only reading the greater than 0 part.

This is what I have:

```
If Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value > 0 < 0.1 Then
count1 = count1 + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a temporary variable because you have check it two times:

```
dim temp as single
temp = Range("a1").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value

if temp >= 0 and temp < 0.1 then
    ' ...
else if temp >= 0.1 and temp < 0.2 then
    ' ...
'...
```

Or you can do it in a more clever way:

```
dim index as integer
index = temp / 0.1

' et-voilà, you know where to insert it
```

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Dim value As Double

value = Range("a1").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value

If value > 0 And value < 0.1 Then
  ' ...
End If
```